# Reflection.Emit: Get a MethodInfo for a constructed type having GenericTypeParameterBuilder type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, reflection.emit

I'm trying to `Reflection.Emit` a generic class that implements a generic interface constructed with the class's generic parameter, like e.g. this:

```
class Foo<U>: IEquatable<U>
{
    bool IEquatable<U>.Equals(U other) { /* ... */ }
}
```

I'm struggling to get a `MethodInfo` for the `IEquatable<U>.Equals(U)` method.

Reflecting the constructed type `IEquatable<U>` throws a `NotSupportedException` because `U` is a `GenericTypeParameterBuilder`, whereas `TypeBuilder.GetMethod(IEquatable<U>, IEquatable<T>.Equals(T))` returns a weird `IEquatable<U>.Equals(T)` method.

Any help appreciated!

Test code:

```
// define class Foo<U>
var tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType("Foo");
var genParams = tb.DefineGenericParameters("U");

// IEquatable<T>.Equals(T) method
var miEqualsT = typeof(IEquatable<>).GetMethod("Equals", typeof(IEquatable<>).GetGenericArguments());

// IEquatable<U> constructed type
var iEquatableU = typeof(IEquatable<>).MakeGenericType(genParams);

// now trying to get IEquatable<U>.Equals(U) method
MethodInfo miEqualsU;
try { miEqualsU = iEquatableU.GetMethod("Equals", genParams); }
catch (NotSupportedException) { Console.WriteLine("Reflecting constructed interface not supported."); }

miEqualsU = TypeBuilder.GetMethod(iEquatableU, miEqualsT);
var declaringType =$"{miEqualsU.DeclaringType.Name}<{miEqualsU.DeclaringType.GenericTypeArguments[0].Name}>";
var parameterType = miEqualsU.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
Console.WriteLine($"TypeBuilder.GetMethod() returns {declaringType}.{miEqualsU.Name}({parameterType.Name})");

// OUTPUT:
// Reflecting constructed interface not supported.
// TypeBuilder.GetMethod() returns IEquatable`1<U>.Equals(T)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the correct method with `miEqualsT` already. Here's how you'd implement the interface with the method:

```
var assemblyName = new AssemblyName { Name = "asd" };
var moduleBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run).DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName.Name);

var tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType("Foo");
var genParams = tb.DefineGenericParameters("U");
var miEqualsT = typeof(IEquatable<>).GetMethod("Equals", typeof(IEquatable<>).GetGenericArguments());

var myMethod = tb.DefineMethod("Equals", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual, typeof(bool), genParams);

var il = myMethod.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "I was invoked!");
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, GetMethod<string>(a => Console.WriteLine(a)));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

tb.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IEquatable<>).MakeGener‌​icType(genParams));
tb.DefineMethodOverride(myMethod, miEqualsT);

var t = tb.CreateType();
```

```
//Hack for demonstration
private MethodInfo GetMethod<T>(Expression<Action<T>> thing)
{
    return ((thing as LambdaExpression).Body as MethodCallExpression).Method;
}
```

And then using it:

```
var genericType = t.MakeGenericType(typeof(int));
var tObj = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);

var method = genericType.GetMethods()
    .Where(m => m.Name == "Equals" && m.DeclaringType == genericType)
    .First();

method.Invoke(tObj, new object[] { 5 });
```

Or:

```
var tObj = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
DoIt(tObj as IEquatable<int>);
```

```
private void DoIt(IEquatable<int> obj)
{
    obj.Equals(5);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think the OP was overthinking the problem and trying to get all his ducks in a row and was thinking he needed the `MethodInfo` for `IEquatable<U>.Equals(U o)` -- where the method info was reified.  In practice, such a method info object is unnecssary as all you need to do is define a method with the correct _signature_ (as you've done) and then you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I noticed it does work that way, but didn't believe it to be correct. Turns out we emit something equivalent to `class Foo<U>: IEquatable<T>{ bool IEquatable<T>.Equals(U other) {/*...*/} }`, which seems odd. But I see that it (`TypeBuilder.CreateType()`?) can be made sense of since we never can have `class Foo<U,V>: IEquatable<U>, IEquatable<V>`. Still surprised that we have to "implement" a generic type definition.

Comment: @tinudu Having another look, I'm curious how the original code I wrote even works. It appears to me the code should be: `tb.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IEquatable<>).MakeGenericType(genParams))`. After a bit of testing (making `Foo<U,T>` and adding implementation `IEquatable<>`) yields `Foo<U,T> : IEquatable<U>`, so I'm not too sure what happens behind the scenes in terms of assigning generic arguments. We need to explicitly add the implementation for *any* method (not just generics) - we're just spoiled with C# automatically providing an implementation based on matching signatures